# add rows in datatable on runtime with sql query

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2008, datagridview, datatable

I have Textbox1, dataGridView and a Button on my winform application.
Scenario is: When button is pressed, SQL Query is run based upon value entered in textbox. And the data fetched by this query in inserted in the dataGridview (dataTable). Till here, My code is working.
But  When I type other value in the text box and press button it replaces the the record present in the dataGridview (dataTable).
I want that each time when I type some value in textbox and press button, that should add row() in the dataGridview (dataTable). It should not replace previous added data.
Here is my code: I need to fulfill requirement that, New added data should not replace previous one.
Thanks in advance. 

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=AFZAL\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=GIMS_LabInfo;Integrated Security=True");
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand("select Profcode, Profname, Profcharges, Profduedate from Profnames$ Where Profname = '"+comboBox1.Text+"'", con);
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(sc);

            DataTable ds = new DataTable();

                 sda.Fill(ds);
            dataGridView2.DataSource = ds;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a global variable that contains the rows loaded in your grid by the various queries and it is used to bind its content to the DataGridView.

```
DataTable currentData = null;
```

then, after the first query, you use the [DataTable.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.copy(v=vs.110).aspx) method to copy table and data returned by the query and bind this `currentData` to the datagrid.
The next queries add the rows extracted to the `currentData` table using the [LoadDataRow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kcy03ww2(v=vs.110).aspx) method

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(....))
        using(SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand(@"select Profcode, Profname, Profcharges,  
                                     Profduedate from Profnames$ 
                                     Where Profname =  @name", con))
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name",comboBox1.Text);
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(sc);

            DataTable ds = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(ds);

            if(currentData == null)
            {
                currentData = ds.Copy();
                dataGridView2.DataSource = currentData;
            }
            else
            {
                currentData.BeginLoadData();
                foreach(DataRow row in ds.Rows)
                   currentData.LoadDataRow(row.ItemArray, true);
                currentData.EndLoadData();

            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Notice also that I have removed the string concatenation in building the command text and used instead a parameterized query. Also the using statement ensures a proper closing and disposing of command and connection used.

Comment: Thank you so much @steve. But I am getting error here on this line currentData.LoadDataRow(row.ItemArray); Error : No overload for method 'LoadDataRow' takes '1' arguments

Comment: True, I have not checked the docs correctly. There is another parameter to keep the rows added in the Unchanged state. Answer updated

Comment: Thank you sooooooo much steve. I was doing it for last 4 days but could not succeed. You did it man! Thank you once again :)

Comment: Can i ask for little more help please? I want to have sum of Profcharges column in textbox2. Please help me in this as well.
Thanks.

Comment: @AfzalQazi if you have another question the best approach to have it solved is to post another question (You can even link back to this if they have a common background) If you ask another question in a comment the only one to know your problem is me limiting you possibilities to have it solved as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you don't have any command to add the value from the TextBox to the DataGridView.  The code to add the value should be something like this:

dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = textBox1.Text;

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to clear your to datagridview before insert data source in the  grid view .
so on your button click first do this

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
```